# Clarification on ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I recently read about submitting tasks to an `ExecutorService`, where the tasks implement the `Runnable` interface. Please correct my me if I am wrong but:

- It is my understanding that you can create a `ThreadPool` and specifically define how many threads this pool can contain. Is the reason for doing this over creating a cached thread pool that the latter can crash if you feed it too many tasks? Also, I am wondering, what is the maximum value you can pass in for the number of threads you want your thread pool to contain? What's to stop me from passing an arbitrarily large integer that makes no sense, say 100000?
- What exactly is the benefit of even using an `ExecutorService`? I understand that it abstracts some of the instantiation/handling of your task for you, but I guess other than that I don't understand much more on a deeper level

Is that true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To answer your first point:**

> It is my understanding that you can create a ThreadPool and
>   specifically define how many threads this pool can contain. Is the
>   reason for doing this over creating a cached thread pool that the
>   latter can crash if you feed it too many tasks?

There are many implementations of ExecutorService like `newCachedThreadPool()`, `newCachedThreadPool(ThreadFactory threadFactory)`, `newFixedThreadPool(int nThreads)`, many of which creates a cached thread pool and many not, like fixed thread pool. **Fixed thread pool is not a replacement of cached thread pool, but they both are options.**
So, developer should choose depending on the requirement. If you want to take full control of the thread pool then have a fixed size thread pool, and there will be guarantee that no matter how many tasks are there, in the pool there will be only those many threads, which means in your application there will be only those many extra threads.

> Also, I am wondering, what is the maximum value you can pass in for
>   the number of threads you want your thread pool to contain? What's to
>   stop me from passing an arbitrarily large integer that makes no sense,
>   say 100000?

To the best of my knowledge, there is no hardline rule defined on how many threads you can put in your thread pool. It really depends upon how many threads your JVM can handle. For example, **32 bit JVM can handle lesser number of threads than 64 bit JVM**. So, if you are on 64 bit JVM then you can more luxury.
Nothing stops a developer from putting some non-sense number, but then *there will consequence in terms of hogging threads, performance degradation, out of memory, or even JVM crash.*

**To answer your second point:**

> What exactly is the benefit of even using an ExecutorService? I
>   understand that it abstracts some of the instantiation/handling of
>   your task for you, but I guess other than that I don't understand much
>   more on a deeper level

The real advantage comes from the fact that you are **programming to interface**. So, you can choose several `ExecutorService` implementations like `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`, `ThreadPoolExecutor` etc. Also, there are host of other options you do if you are using `ExecutorService` like

- start a thread after fixed interval
- invoke any tasks in one shot and let your thread pool execute them

Read methods available in `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` and `ThreadPoolExecutor`, and you will realize the power of methods they provide.

Hope this helps!

---

**Edit: Based on input from @pens-fan-69**
Read [this article](http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-what-limit-number-threads) on how many threads JVM can support.

### Stack Size

Entire JVM process consists of Java threads, some are internal JVM threads like main thread, GC threads, finalizer thread etc. while some are user defined threads. 
 
 Irrespective of whether it is internal or user defined thread,  *each thread will have a portion of stack assigned to it to put runtime information.* JVM parameter **-Xss** defines the stack size. For example, if stack size (-Xss) is 64KB then it means that each threads in JVM will have 64KB to store runtime information.

If the stack size falls short then stack overflow exception is thrown.

So, the maximum number of threads that can exist in JVM will depend upon the stack size. **Larger the stack size, lesser number of threads, and vice-versa.**

Default stack size will vary based on OS. Diagram below:
[image]

Comment: Good explanation. The only thing I would add is that the underlying operating system usually DOES have an upper limit on light weight processes (aka threads), if for no other reason that the limited amount of memory available for the thread stacks. As a result, you wouldn't be able to start an arbitrarily large number of Java threads in practice.

Comment: @pens-fan-69 Thanks, good point, I have tried to put something for maximum number of threads in JVM.

Answer (score 2):

1. The reason why there is a fixed thread pool is that you may need to limit the number of threads your application creates (and control resource usage). There is no clear limit for the number of threads per process, it depends on the OS and host (usually memory).
2. The benefit of using executor services is that you can change your multi-threaded behaviour just by replacing one implementation with another. Say, you can switch from a limited number of threads to a cached thread pool just by calling a different method on `Executors` and your code doesn't need to be changed.

Answer (score 2):

1. Starting up threads is expensive and should be avoided where possible. The thread pool caches threads so that it does this less often.
2. Threads are a limited resource that you can run out of so it's best to limit the maximum number that are started. You can increase the number if items in the queue are not being processed quickly enough but you can do it in a controlled manner so that you don't crash the JVM because you reached the maximum. The maximum supported will be determined by the OS configuration and hardware you are using.
3. I like creating a single thread pool for an entire application and then using it for all types of background work. In a web application you have to make sure that your threads are ended when the application is stopped. Having a single thread pool makes this easy. Otherwise you'll constantly run into thread leaks because you forgot to stop threads.

Yes, I know it is not recommended to start threads in web applications. It works fine for me as long as you end them.